# Не применяется Stylesheet для QKeySequenceEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qkeysequenceedit

Проблема заключается в том, что `QKeySequenceEdit` не хочет применять `stylesheet`.

Оно изменяется только тогда когда я напрямую задаю этот стиль. то есть:

```py
self.keySequenceEdit.setStyleSheet("background: rgb(255, 255, 0)")
```

вот код:

```
from sys import argv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(220, 40)
        self.setStyleSheet("/*#keySequenceEdit {"
                                 "    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"
                                 "    border: 1px solid;"
                                 "    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"
                                 "}*/"
                                 "/*QKeySequenceEdit {"
                                 "    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"
                                 "    border: 1px solid;"
                                 "    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"
                                 "}*/")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.keySequenceEdit = QtWidgets.QKeySequenceEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.keySequenceEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 200, 20))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(argv)
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю попробовать так:

```
from sys import argv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.keySequenceEdit = QtWidgets.QKeySequenceEdit()
        self.keySequenceEdit.setObjectName("keySequenceEdit")

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Просто Label', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter))
        layout.addWidget(self.keySequenceEdit, stretch=1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Просто Button'))
                                 

Stylesheet = '''
#centralwidget {
    background-color: #3FA796;
    border: 3px solid #FEC260;
}

QLineEdit {
    border-radius: 10px; 
    border: 3px solid #1A3C40; 
    color: #FAFDD6; 
    background: #A64B2A;
}
QKeySequenceEdit {
    font: 19pt \"Segoe UI Semilight\"; 
    color: blue; 
}        
QPushButton {
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-width: 6em;
    font: 12pt \"Segoe UI Semibold\";
}
QLabel {font: 18pt \"Segoe UI Semilight\"; }

'''                                 
                                 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(220, 40)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Kickwall что не так?